# What is the renew behavior on deactivated base plan in Android app auto-renew subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, android-billing

In [Google's document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en) (actually, it is Play Console Help though), it is said that:

> **Deactivate or reactivate a base plan**
> You can deactivate a base plan to prevent new purchases. **It does not affect any existing subscriptions.**

But, I'm wondering what happens when the existing subscriptions automatically renew since it is not written there. I think it's absolutely natural that they are blocked from renewing since the associated base plan is deactivated, but I'm not 100% sure if it is true.

Is there any official statement about it? Or does anyone know about its actual behavior from real experience?

Comment: @ewokx You're right. Still I want to confirm I'm not missing their official document/statement just in case